# New top bar FUBAR in IE on SPSE

Tags: support, bug, design

The new top bar is nice, but it really is messed up graphic-wise in IE 11.
In SO it also caps the characters that go below the [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Typography_Line_Terms.svg).

[image: SharePoint StackExchange]
[image: Stack Overflow]

Who are responsible for the new CSS and how do we get it fixed?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in IE11.0.9600, Windows 8.1.

Comment: hmm... only settings I have custom on my IE is my rather nazi cookie settings, but can't see how that relates. Alsoit looksfine on the App version on my Windows Surfacerunning Win 8.1 RT

Comment: Can it be your 5 digit reputation / nbr of badges messing stuff up? That would be kind of funny :)

Comment: @Jin did you do anything about this? I dont have the issue any more this morning

Comment: @AndersRask Nope I didn't do anything.

Comment: gah now its Fubar again. I think it has something to do with the browser being upgraded from win 8.1 prerelease

Answer (score 2):

(using an answer to be able to post a screen)

Currently using win 7 + ie 11 RTM. I don't see the aforementioned bug. Are you using win8?
Also, any idea why the update version is different?? Maybe you upgraded from the pre-release version? Or it is me using an old version (a good reason to NOT upgrade, then)?

[image]

Comment: Same, I have Win8.1 and IE11 and the top bar looks fine. Maybe tinker with compatibility settings (and try a CTRL+R in case some old styles have been cached).

Comment: no custom setings except cookies. I (of couse) nuked my cached files with CTRL+F5 before posting. It's anofficial release, and did a scratch install not upgrade (did have pre-release before)